# MySql add conditional state on duplicate key and if not duplicate key

Tags: mysql, database

is there a way to add condition like "if not duplicate key"?

```
MySql_Connection.query("
    INSERT INTO `my_database`.my_table (`word`) VALUES ("word_to_insert") 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `hits` = `hits` + 1
    // ON **NOT** DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `hits` = `hits` + 2;
");
```

the following is not a good solution for my case

```
MySql_Connection.query("
    INSERT INTO `my_database`.my_table (`word`) VALUES ("word_to_insert") 
    UPDATE `hits` = `hits` + 2
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `hits` = `hits` + 1;
");
```

because it will by default increase by 2 always

Comment: Is `word` the primary key?

Comment: yes it's the primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to decrease it if duplicate to avoid it:

```
INSERT INTO `my_database`.my_table (`word`) VALUES ("word_to_insert") 
    UPDATE `hits` = `hits` + 2
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `hits` = `hits` - 1;
```

If no duplicate: `+2`
If duplicate `+2-1 = +1`

Answer (score 1):

I guess that word is the primary key.

If you do this, you will get 2 hits when a word is added, otherwise add 1 to hits:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(word, hits) VALUES('word_to_insert', 2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+1
```